# How to refresh individual query cache in ColdFusion 2016

Tags: caching, coldfusion, refresh, query-cache, coldfusion-2016

I found a piece of code that works under the ColdFusion 10 engine, but not under the ColdFusion 2016 (CF12) engine.

I have a CFC that houses cached queries that are grabbed by function calls.  Say I have a query I want to cache, but I make a change to the db table that this query uses.  I do not see the data in the returned cached query, so I need to refresh the query cache, simple enough.  This is how I have my code set up:

```
<cffunction name="getVariables" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfargument name="time_span" required="true" default="#this.cacheSpan#" />
    <cfset var qryGetVariables="">

    <!--- IF REFRESH, NEW QRYTIMESPAN --->
    <cfif arguments.time_span eq 0 AND NOT this.bln_refresh>
        <!--- IF time_span 0 but not refresh, reset to original cache span --->
        <cfset arguments.time_span = this.cacheSpan />
    </cfif>
    <cfquery name="qryGetVariables" datasource="#this.dsn#" cachedwithin="#arguments.time_span#">
        select *
          from get_variables
         order by id, value
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn qryGetVariables>
</cffunction>
```

I call a function in the same CFC that refreshes this query in the following manner:

```
this.bln_refresh = true;
<cfinvoke method="getVariables" returnvariable="qryReturn">
   <cfinvokeargument name="time_span" value="0" />
</cfinvoke>
this.bln_refresh = false;
```

Again, this worked before on ColdFusion 10 but now it does not work on ColdFusion 2016.  What do I need to do differently to refresh the cache of this specific query?

Comment: I don't work with version 2016, but the absence of an argument type might be relevant.  By the way, what does `does not work` mean?

Comment: What I mean is when I refresh the cachedwithin timespan variable, it should refresh the cached query to update it with the new values I've added in the DB.  "Does not work" means that when I do a refresh via CFC method, by passing the argument of 0 for timespan, the cached query is not refreshed.  It still displays the old values not the new ones, and this worked before in CF10.

Comment: @user1100412 I'm glad you found a solution. Instead of including the solution in your question add it as a new answer to this question and accept it. It is okay to answer your own question here. Just give proper credit as you have done.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much thanks to [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1769733/alex), I came across the following solution that appears to be working on our servers:

```
<cffunction name="getVariables" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfargument name="time_span" required="true" default="#this.cacheSpan#" />
    <cfset var qryGetVariables="" />
    <cfset var flt_qryTimeSpan=0>

    <cfif NOT cacheIdExists("qryGetVariablesCache") OR this.bln_refresh>
        <cfquery name="qryGetVariables" datasource="#this.dsn#" cachedwithin="#flt_qryTimeSpan#">
            select *
              from get_variables
             order by id, value
        </cfquery>
        <cfset cacheRemove("qryGetVariablesCache") />
        <cfset cachePut("qryGetVariablesCache",qryGetVariables,this.cacheSpan) />
    <cfelse>
        <cfset qryGetVariables = cacheGet("qryGetVariablesCache") />
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn qryGetVariables>

</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this has changed after CF10. [It's considered as bug, but it still not fixed.](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4198513) Once a query result is cached using `cachedWithin`, it cannot be invalidated using `createTimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0)` (equal to `0`) or any negative value.

## Demo

```
<!--- cache data for 10 minutes --->
<cfquery cachedWithin="#createTimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0)#">
    SELECT `foo` FROM `example`;
</cfquery>
```

| foo
|-----
| ABC

Let's change the data.

```
UPDATE `example` SET `foo` = 'DEF';
```

And as expected...

```
<!--- invalidate cache and fetch new data --->
<cfquery cachedWithin="#createTimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0)#">
    SELECT `foo` FROM `example`;
</cfquery>
```

| foo
|-----
| DEF

And now let's cache the most recent data.

```
<!--- cache new data for 10 minutes --->
<cfquery cachedWithin="#createTimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0)#">
    SELECT `foo` FROM `example`;
</cfquery>
```

## Result in CF10

| foo
|-----
| DEF

`cachedWithin <= 0` invalidated the cached query. Thus the next `cachedWithin > 0` stored the new data in cache.

## Result in CF2016

| foo
|-----
| ABC

`cachedWithin <= 0` simply skipped the cache. The next `cachedWithin > 0` fetches from cache. And the cache didn't change.

---

## UPDATE

The current workaround for this bug is using the `cacheID` attribute of `<cfquery>` and then invalidate using `cacheRemove(theCacheID)`.

## Old Answer

You can invalidate the query cache using `<cfobjectcache action="CLEAR">`, **but** it invalidates ALL cached queries, which is pretty bad. The other option is caching the query by yourself using [`cachePut`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/CachePut.html) and fetching it using [`cacheGet`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/CacheGet.html).

Here is a hint how to do it. You might have to incorporate your `this.cacheSpan` logic in here, I'm not really sure what the goal of it is:

```
<cffunction name="getVariables" access="public" returntype="query">

    <cfargument name="time_span" required="true" default="#this.cacheSpan#">

    <cfset var qryGetVariables = "">

    <cfset var cacheKey = "qryGetVariables"> <!--- make sure the key is unique and only used in this function --->
    <cfset var useCache = ((arguments.time_span lte 0) or this.bln_refresh)>

    <cfif useCache>
        <cfset qryGetVariables = cacheGet(cacheKey)>
    </cfif>

    <cfif not isQuery(qryGetVariables)>

        <cfquery name="qryGetVariables" datasource="#this.dsn#">
            select *
              from get_variables
             order by id, value
        </cfquery>

        <cfset cachePut(cacheKey, qryGetVariables, arguments.time_span)>

    </cfif>

    <cfreturn qryGetVariables>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Does Adobe identify this change anywhere?  (This is rather major issue for all of the applications I've written and it looks like it will take a lot of extra work to invalidate or clear a specific cached query.)

Comment: @JamesMoberg It's a confirmed bug that needs fixing: https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4198513

Comment: Thanks.  I'm dynamically adding a column w/values to a query. Subsequent re-queries return the modified query instead of the initial cached one. https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/fe7ff5be43560ba6f8b6c513fdf9f723 (This may not be the same bug, but is just as serious.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what @Alex says is correct or not, but I have no reason to doubt him. I am not running ColdFusion 2016. Perhaps this is another option to refresh the cache for a specific query...

Remember that when using the `cachedWithin` attribute of the `cfquery` tag it will only cache a query when all of the following is true. "*Takes effect only if query caching is enabled in the Administrator. To use cached data, the current query must use the same SQL statement, data source, query name, user name, and password.*" ([cfquery documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfquery.html))

Focusing on this part - **the same SQL statement**. If you change the SQL statement slightly the cache will be refreshed. So maybe you can just add another condition to your SQL statement that you can use to refresh the query. You may even be able to use the same variable you have already `time_span`.

I am thinking something like this (the syntax may vary depending on your DBMS):

```
<cfquery name="qryGetVariables" datasource="#this.dsn#" cachedwithin="#arguments.time_span#">
    select *
    from get_variables
    where '#arguments.time_span#' = '#arguments.time_span#'
    order by id, value
</cfquery>
```

The condition should always be true so the query will return the same result set.

*I have not tested this.

Comment: I've reported a similar issue to CF team via Slack that's even more serious than this cachedWithin bug.  The CF Team is "evaluating further" to determine how to fix it.  My issue was regarding subsequent queries not actually returning & refreshing the query variable from the cache.
https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/fe7ff5be43560ba6f8b6c513fdf9f723 (I can't upgrade from CF9/10 until this is fixed.)